# Select specific properties from include ones in entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 2.0 and have this 2 classes:

News

```cs
public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate{ get; set; }
    public int AuthorID{ get; set; }
    public Author Author{ get; set; }
}
```

Author

```cs
public class Author 
{
    public Author ()
    {
     News = new List<News>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<News> News {get;set;}
}
```

I want to load the news with the author's username only because I don't need the other information like author's first and lastname.

If I execute this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var ctx = new DbContext())
  {
   var result= ctx.News.Include(x => x.Author).Select(news => new
   {
     news= news ,
     Username= pr.Author.Username
   }).ToList();
  }
}
```

Entity Framework Core 2.0 generates a database query like:

```sql
SELECT [x].[ID], [x].[Text], [x].[Title], [x].[AuthorId], [x].[ReleaseDate], [x.Author].[ID], [x.Verfasser].[Username] AS [Username], [x.Verfasser].[Firstname], [x.Verfasser].[Lastname]
FROM [News] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Author] AS [x.Author] ON [x].[AuthorId] = [x.Author].[ID]
```

Is there a way to achieve my expected behaviour?

Comment: I assume `x.Verfasser` should be `x.Author`?

Comment: Did you get this working? I want to perform same operation. With Employee data I just want to fetch RoleName. but Navigation property loads entire Role object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to load the `Author` entity (because there is no way to load entity with just some non navigation properties populated).

Then the question is why did you specifically add `Include(x => x.Author)` which is requesting EF to load the `Author`. `Include` / `ThenInclude` methods support *eager loading of the related data entities*. They are not needed when you use projection (`Select`).

Interestingly, all EF (Core) versions before EFC 2.0 were ignoring includes for projection type queries. Even the current EFC documentation states that the projection queries fall into [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) category. However, as you've noticed EFC 2.0 is not ignoring it! So it's either implementation bug and will be fixed, or the documentation bug and will be updated.

For now, simply don't use `Include` in projection queries. If you execute this:

```cs
var result = ctx.News.Select(news => new
{
    news = news,
    Username = news.Author.Username
}).ToList();
```

the EFC generated SQL query now is as expected:

```sql
SELECT [news].[Id], [news].[AuthorID], [news].[ReleaseDate], [news].[Text], [news].[Title], [news.Author].[Username]
FROM [News] AS [news]
INNER JOIN [Authors] AS [news.Author] ON [news].[AuthorID] = [news.Author].[Id]
```

Comment: If I understand (and observe) ef-core's behavior correctly, it now includes navigation properties of all entity type instances that are in the end result, even when they're in a projection, `news` in this case. But admittedly, the documentation is rather vague at this point.

Comment: Hi @Gert, I didn't test fully with different projection/Include combinations, hence cannot say what's the exact behavior/rule, but looks like the Includes of the query start entity are now considered if the start entity is included in the projection as in this example. About documentation - no comment. Working with EFC from the beginning is on trial and error principle :(

Comment: I've already given new answers and changed some of my old answers to tell people about this new behavior, so I sincerely hope it's correct :) I think its a great improvement because it makes `Include` more intuitive, or should I say less counter-intuitive?

Comment: This solution also significantly increases the loading speed. I stumbled upon this answer looking for a way to increase my query speed. Through "trial and error" I thought maybe if I just grabbed what I needed, then it would help. Well sure enough, it did. I went from about an average of 4500ms loading time to an average 140ms loading time. HUGE increase.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using an anonymous object, you create a `NewsDTO` class with the properties you want to retrieve (example bellow).

```cs
public class NewsDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate{ get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can return from your repository layer a method `Task<NewsDTO> GetSpecificProperties()`.

I prefer to use [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/), your code will be cleaner:

```cs
return context.NewsTable.ProjectTo<NewsDTO>().ToList()
```

But you can do using this odd kind

```cs
return context.NewsTable
.Include(x => x.Author)
.Select(x => new NewsDTO
        {
            Id = x.Id.,
            Title = x.Title,
            Text = x.Text,
            ReleaseDate = x.ReleaseDate,
            AuthorName = x.Author.Username
        }).ToList();
```

Obs: Database retrieve data just when you use `.ToList()`, before this is just `IQueryable`, so if you have a where clause, prefer use before retrieve data.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to return `IQueryable` to other layers.

Comment: You're right Yuri Cardoso, i edited the answer