# How to query EF Core dbcontext for specific attributes from navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm trying to get the most efficient query for selecting some nested attributes in navigation properties so the API sends a response which contains only relevant information. So far I tried the `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` approach and the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476117/select-specific-properties-from-include-ones-in-entity-framework-core).

However both approaches produced similar queries and retrieved the same columns from the database. The only noticeable difference being that the Include approach loaded the data from unneeded columns into the entity object attributes while the `Select()` approach didn't. I'm using a layer pattern so using null type isn't much of an option for me and the nul values in the entity aren't a problem as only the retrieves values are eventually loaded into the dto, but still the query efficiency question remains.

My question is if there is a better way to query single columns from navigation properties and if not which of the two mentioned ways is better.

Include query method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Orden>> GetDetailed()
{
    return await _context.Ordenes
                         .Include(o => o.Detalles)
                         .ThenInclude(od => od.ProductosAlmacenados)
                         .Include(o => o.Detalles)
                         .ThenInclude(od => od.Tela)
                         .Include(o => o.Detalles)
                         .ThenInclude(od => od.Color)
                         .ToListAsync();
}
```

`Select()` query method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Orden>> GetDetailed()
{
    var ordenes = await _context.Ordenes
                                .Select(o => new Orden
        {
            Id = o.Id,
            Estatus = o.Estatus,
            FechaRegistro = o.FechaRegistro,
            FechaRequerida = o.FechaRequerida,
            Detalles = o.Detalles.Select(d => new OrdenDetalles
            {
                Color = new Color
                {
                    Nombre = d.Color.Nombre
                },
                Tela = new Tela
                {
                    Nombre = d.Tela.Nombre,
                },
                Cantidad = d.Cantidad,
                ProductosAlmacenados = d.ProductosAlmacenados
            }).ToList()
        }
        ).ToListAsync();

    return ordenes;
}
```

Query generated by `Select` with output:

```
SELECT `o`.`ID`, `o`.`Estatus`, `o`.`Fecha_Registro`, `o`.`Fecha_Requerida`, `t0`.`Nombre`, `t0`.`Nombre0`, `t0`.`Cantidad`, `t0`.`Color_ID`, `t0`.`Orden_ID`, `t0`.`Tela_ID`, `t0`.`ID`, `t0`.`ID0`, `t0`.`Almacen_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Tela_ID`, `t0`.`Cantidad0`
  FROM `orden` AS `o`
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT `c`.`Nombre`, `t`.`Nombre` AS `Nombre0`, `o0`.`Cantidad`, `o0`.`Color_ID`, `o0`.`Orden_ID`, `o0`.`Tela_ID`, `c`.`ID`, `t`.`ID` AS `ID0`, `a`.`Almacen_ID`, `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`, `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`, `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Tela_ID`, `a`.`Cantidad` AS `Cantidad0`
      FROM `ordendetalles` AS `o0`
      INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON `o0`.`Color_ID` = `c`.`ID`
      INNER JOIN `tela` AS `t` ON `o0`.`Tela_ID` = `t`.`ID`
      LEFT JOIN `almacen_productos` AS `a` ON ((`o0`.`Color_ID` = `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`) AND (`o0`.`Orden_ID` = `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`)) AND (`o0`.`Tela_ID` = `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Tela_ID`)
  ) AS `t0` ON `o`.`ID` = `t0`.`Orden_ID`
  ORDER BY `o`.`ID`, `t0`.`Color_ID`, `t0`.`Orden_ID`, `t0`.`Tela_ID`, `t0`.`ID`, `t0`.`ID0`, `t0`.`Almacen_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`
```

[MySQlWorkbench output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zXRQ.png)

Query generated by `Include()`:

```
SELECT `o`.`ID`, `o`.`Estatus`, `o`.`Fecha_Registro`, `o`.`Fecha_Requerida`, `t0`.`Color_ID`, `t0`.`Orden_ID`, `t0`.`Tela_ID`, `t0`.`Cantidad`, `t0`.`ID`, `t0`.`ID0`, `t0`.`Almacen_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Tela_ID`, `t0`.`Cantidad0`, `t0`.`Nombre`, `t0`.`Nombre0`
  FROM `orden` AS `o`
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT `o0`.`Color_ID`, `o0`.`Orden_ID`, `o0`.`Tela_ID`, `o0`.`Cantidad`, `t`.`ID`, `c`.`ID` AS `ID0`, `a`.`Almacen_ID`, `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`, `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`, `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Tela_ID`, `a`.`Cantidad` AS `Cantidad0`, `t`.`Nombre`, `c`.`Nombre` AS `Nombre0`
      FROM `ordendetalles` AS `o0`
      INNER JOIN `tela` AS `t` ON `o0`.`Tela_ID` = `t`.`ID`
      INNER JOIN `color` AS `c` ON `o0`.`Color_ID` = `c`.`ID`
      LEFT JOIN `almacen_productos` AS `a` ON ((`o0`.`Color_ID` = `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`) AND (`o0`.`Orden_ID` = `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`)) AND (`o0`.`Tela_ID` = `a`.`OrdenDetalles_Tela_ID`)
  ) AS `t0` ON `o`.`ID` = `t0`.`Orden_ID`
  ORDER BY `o`.`ID`, `t0`.`Color_ID`, `t0`.`Orden_ID`, `t0`.`Tela_ID`, `t0`.`ID`, `t0`.`ID0`, `t0`.`Almacen_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Color_ID`, `t0`.`OrdenDetalles_Orden_ID`
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL7gU.png)

`Orden` entity:

```
public partial class Orden
{
    public Orden()
    {
        Detalles = new HashSet<OrdenDetalles>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaRequerida { get; set; }
    public Estado Estatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrdenDetalles> Detalles { get; set; }
}
```

`OrdenDetalles` entity:

```
public partial class OrdenDetalles
{
    public OrdenDetalles()
    {
        ProductosAlmacenados = new HashSet<ProductoAlmacenado>();
    }

    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public int OrdenId { get; set; }
    public int TelaId { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }

    public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
    public virtual Orden Orden { get; set; }
    public virtual Tela Tela { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductoAlmacenado> ProductosAlmacenados { get; set; }
}
```

If any other information is needed please let me know in the comments

Comment: Hi, (1) What EF Core version are you targeting? (2) Is [lazy loading with proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-with-proxies) enabled for your db context?

Comment: However, inside `Detalles` select you have `Cantidad = d.Cantidad` and `ProductosAlmacenados = d.ProductosAlmacenados`, which are full entity projections, hence have the same effect as `Include`.  So the only difference between the two queries is selecting `Color` and `Tela`, and in case they have just 2 properties (PK and `Nombre`), the selected columns in the query will be the same. If you want to see a difference, do `Candidad = new Candidad { ... }` and/or `ProductosAlmacenados = d.ProductosAlmacenados.Select(...).ToList()` where `...` are few properties of the full entity,

Comment: I'm using the EF Core 6.0, I haven't enabled lazy loading. I can't use `new Cantidad` as  `Cantidad` is an int attribute and not a navigation property, tried your suggestion on ProductosAlmacenados, which represents the storage for products, but still got the 17 column table query when I only need 8 values per entry. I did `ProductosAlmacenados = d.ProductosAlmacenados.Select(pa => new ProductoAlmacenado{Cantidad = pa.Cantidad}).ToList()`
From ProductosAlmacenados y only need the stock(`Cantidad`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projection using Select is generally the better approach however, do not use `Select` to populate Entity classes, rather populate DTOs or ViewModel POCO classes that contain just the details you need.

The reason you don't want to populate Entity classes partially with just the details you need is because those instances no longer represent complete entities, they are partial shells of entities. Any method that expects to receive an entity could be passed one of these incomplete entities with things like default values and #nulls. Using a DTO definition avoids any confusion about what data would be coming through.

When querying across an entity graph you can flatten the details from related entities into fields or a different structure. While the SQL won't look that different at a glance, projection generally reduces the amount of data traveling over the wire and also allows you to tune indexing for high-usage scenarios which can significantly improve performance.

So for instance you could flatten the DTO to something like:

```
var ordenes = await _context.Ordenes
    .Select(o => new OrdenDto
    {
        Id = o.Id,
        Estatus = o.Estatus,
        FechaRegistro = o.FechaRegistro,
        FechaRequerida = o.FechaRequerida,
        Detalles = o.Detalles.Select(d => new OrdenDetallesDto
        {
            ColorNombre = d.Color.Nombre,
            TelaNombre = d.Tela.Nombre,
            Cantidad = d.Cantidad,
            ProductosAlmacenados = d.ProductosAlmacenados
        }).ToList()
    }).ToListAsync();

return ordenes;
```

Comment: I understand you and have read about similar approaches, however I'm using a Repository layer, I've read posts advicing against it in EF but I'd rather stick to what I know to keep it organized,  so using DTO in Repo layer feels wrong. Is there any other way other than using DTO? Linq, using Join? For me anything that isn't raw SQL and allows me to keep my project as it is structured is an answer. Could it be that EF core just can't simplify the query at that depth of nesting?

Comment: With the repository pattern you're either using detached entities, entities tracked by request or similarly scoped DbContext, or you can combine with a Unit of Work to work with `IQueryable` and let the consumers do the relevant projections.  My point is that if using entities they should be complete or completable meaning either everything eager loaded, or lazy-loadable. Partially filling entity classes to satisfy a pattern is a flawed implementation of the pattern. The repository abstracts data domain state, any reduction/translation of that should be done outside of that.

Comment: Hmm, so either I implement lazy loading or drop the pattern, right? Would implementing a simplified version of the entity (sounds a lot like a DTO) break the pattern? Sorry for any dumb question it's my first in depth project